# Is $(ad-bc,a+d)$ a prime ideal in $k[a,b,c,d]$ where $k$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to show whether this is true:

> Let $k$ be a field and $k[a,b,c,d]$ be a ring of polynomials. Then the ideal $(ad-bc,a+d)$ is prime.

If it is true, how should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: I would be curious where this came up. It's hard to ignore that this is the trace and determinant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$k[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc,a+d)\cong k[a,b,c]/(a^2+bc)$$

and $a^2+bc$ looks pretty irreducible to me.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I need this to show that $V(ad-bc, a+d)$ is an irreducible closed affine cone in $\mathbb{A}^{4}(k)$.